# How do I boot Ubuntu from my usb flash drive?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, usb, usb-drive

I have been using Windows 7 Home Basic for years, and now I'm bored and my PC is getting slower by the day. So I decided to try Ubuntu. I formatted an 8GB Transcend USB Flash drive and put Ubuntu in it with the help of Universal USB Installer from pendrivelinux.com as instructed [by Ubuntu.com here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

I tried to get help on how to boot from this USB [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) but I couldn't get my PC BIOS Setup to boot from it.

I press Enter to get to the menu as soon as the system starts, then try changing the primary boot to Removable Disk (my flash drive) by getting into the BIOS setup which doesn't help. I also try to change temporary boot location to the flash drive but in vain. The Windows Screen shows up no matter what I do and I never get a hint of the Ubuntu install menu.

I've tried doing this before and was unsuccessful a couple of times, and I really want to try Ubuntu. I want to know the exact steps I should follow to boot Ubuntu 12.10 from my USB stick.

My system specs are:
Microsoft Windows 7 Home Basic
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
System Type X86-based PC
Processor   Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  330   @ 1.60GHz, 1596 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)

Comment: Try another brand of USB key if you can.

Answer (score 1):

do not use the reccomended program ubuntu said to use to make the bootable flash drive as it doesn't work properly.

Istall unetbootin, it is free. Select the ubuntu to install and choose what flash drive to use and it will do everything for you. around 1 hour later everything should be ready. after that you can reboot and choose the usb flash drive to the top of the boot up order menu in the bios. after that the computer should boot into ubuntu. then install ubuntu and go through the steps, in one of the stages it lets you choose if you would like to replace windows 8 with ubuntu or dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu. then it will let make a new partition.

After it finishes install reboot and remove the flash drive and there should be a menu showing you which system you woruld like to boot into every time you switch on your laptop/pc/netbook/mac.

Comment: I agree, Universal sucks, I see many complaints here and in the Forums, use UNetbootin or better yet, Startup Disk Creator.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you have done the following while trying to make a bootable usb drive.

1. Save the .iso file to from the ubuntu.com/downloads
2. Download linux live from http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download and run it.
3. While running the program,insert the usb drive you want to boot ubuntu from and select the .iso file and the program burns it to your usb drive.
4. Boot your laptop from external device(1st priority) and install ubuntu.When the laptop restarts, press F2(in most cases), F8,F10 OR F12.When the BIOS screen appears, go to the boot tab and deselect the 'boot from hard drive' option and make the 'boot from external device' as the first priority.

If you are unable to successfully boot from the usb drive, I would recommend you to make a bootable cd-rom.But there are issues with this type of installation and you maybe required to try a few times due to the compatibility issue of cd-rom these days.

Answer (score 0):

could you try resetting your bios, then change your boot order so the usb is first, disconnect any other usb things you have connected while booting?

if worst comes to worst you could use WUBI if you wish to just try it

Answer (score 0):

After installing your USB, restart your computer. hit Enter immediately, go to start - set your boot menu to Default. It booted my Windows 7 Professional to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unetbootin and press <kbd>F12</kbd> when the brand of your laptop appears on the screen when it boots. choose the `usb storage device` option.